# If/else isn't working and says the else need an if

Tags: java, if-statement, jgrasp

Why does this code work if the `else` immediately follows the `if` like:

```
if (GPA > 3.8);

else  
   System.out.println("words");
```

But, if I add a statement between the "if" and "else" like:

```
if (GPA > 3.8);
   System.out.println("words");

else  
   System.out.println("words");
```

I get an error saying the `else` needs an `if`?

Answer (score 6):

The semi-colon terminates the `if` block, remove it

```
if (GPA > 3.8); // <-- here
```

should be

```
if (GPA > 3.8)
```